# How to disable cx_freeze to autodetect all modules

Tags: python, cx-freeze

cx_freeze build includes all modules, that installed on my machine, so freezed build becomes a huge. How to disable autodetection feature? I just want to build small PyQt application:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

path = sys.path + ["app"]
includes = ["app.core", "app.utils"]
excludes = ["tcl"]
build_exe_options = {
"path": path,
"icon": "resources\icons\clock.ico"}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "app",
        version = "1.1",
        description = "My Application",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("app.py", base=base,
            targetName="app.exe",
            shortcutName="Application",
            shortcutDir="DesktopFolder")])
```

Also I have the my custom  modules, each has a utils submodule, so cx_freeze put wrong module.

How can I set strict list of modules, which i need?

Comment: What modules is it including that it shouldn't be? Can you post the log in a pastebin? Don't forget that you'll need several libraries for PyQt and Python itself.

Comment: It includes all modules, that i have installed on my computer, for example matplotlib, PIL, Tkinter. I have a VM with windows at home, where installed only required minimum(python, and PyQt) and application builds fine. But at work i have a lot of packages + custom  packages, so application fails after build. Here is log. http://pastebin.com/G5tp3QkH. I just want to set required minimum of modules and nothing more =)

Comment: If something in the code loads matplotlib, that could pull in PIL, numpy & tkinter. Try adding matplotlib to 'excludes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was quite simple. 
This application uses a custom modules, so I've added application folder to the path:

```
path = sys.path + ["app"]
```

The trick is that app uses module "utils" and I have other "utils" module in my OS path. Other "utils" module imports a lot of stuff like matplotlib, PIL, etc. 
So I've solved problem by changing path environment like this:

```
path = ["app"] + sys.path
```

So, cx_freeze gets right modules when freeze executable.